# Puppeteer and Headless Chrome Crawler on macOS 11.1 Big Sur

Tags: node.js, macos, puppeteer, chromium

When running [Headless Chrome Crawler](https://github.com/yujiosaka/headless-chrome-crawler/) (hccrawler) on an Intel MacBook Pro with macOS 11.1 (Big Sur) installed, we get the following error:

```
hccrawler:console error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED at https://example.com/some-page
(node:12722) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:156:24)
    at CDPSession.Page.client.on.event (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:132:56)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at CDPSession.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:232:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:119:19)
```

Note: for getting more detailed logs I used the `DEBUG='hccrawler:*'` environment variable.

Versions:

- node.js: 10.16
- Headless Chrome Crawler: 1.8.0
- Puppeteer: 1.5.0

With previous versions of macOS and on Ubuntu it still works without any problem. Any idea what the problem could be? Could it be that the latest macOS version is somehow blocking the Chromium process that is spawn by Puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of headless-chrome-crawler (master branch) resolved the issue. Add this to your your package.json file:

```json
"headless-chrome-crawler": "git://github.com/yujiosaka/headless-chrome-crawler.git#f4004f6f1a27534222703f9161f44815c8eefbe3"
```

or

```json
"headless-chrome-crawler": "git://github.com/yujiosaka/headless-chrome-crawler.git#master"
```

This will install Puppeteer 1.20.0 and Chromium r686378 to your node_modules.

Note: By the time you are reading this there might already be a new release of HCC > 1.8.0, so you might just be able to execute `npm install headless-chrome-crawler@latest`.

Also note that you can use a custom Chromium path as part of the the options that you pass to `hccrawler.launch()`, which can be useful for debugging or quickly trying out other versions:

```js
hccrawler.launch({
  // ...
  executablePath: '/path/to/custom/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium'
});
```

You can also provide the path to your Google Chrome installation if the packaged Chromium version still doesn't work, for example:

```
hccrawler.launch({
  // ...
  executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
});
```